# Launch automation script prior to WO being closed?

Tags: maximo

In Maximo 7.6.1.1:

Is it possible to launch an automation script to update a WO -- just prior to the WO being closed?

[image]

The `Change Status` action seems to happen before any of the launch points that I've tried.

And of course, once a WO is closed, I can't edit the WO with an automation script, since it is flagged as `Is History`.

Answer (score 1):

Which launch points have you tried? I think the earliest you can get is Attribute-Validate, where the `status` value will still have changed, but the action of setting `historyflag` should not have happened, yet. But if that's not working for you, you might be out of luck, unless you're willing to customize the `WORKORDER` object with Java.

Answer (score 1):

You should be good to go with an attribute launchpoint script on the `workorder.status` attribute, event ACTION. I've done it before, I could for example call an API to check funds associated with GL account and block the status change, if necessary.

You just need to check for the current value so other status changes won't be affected.

Python example:

```
if mbo.getString("status") == 'CLOSE':
    #... your code ...
```

Also, remember that you can always use the NOACCESSCHECK flag to change a mbo.
See MboConstants class: https://developer.ibm.com/assetmanagement/7609-maximo-javadoc/

```
from psdi.mbo import MboConstants

mbo.setValue("attribute", value, MboConstants.NOACCESSCHECK)
```